# How to display floating-point numbers with a mantissa set to zero in C++?

Tags: c++

The following code displays floating-point numbers in scientific notation:

```
float foo = 1.0;
::cout::setf(::std::ios::scientific);
::std::cout << foo;
```

It produces this output:

```
1.000000e-000
```

What I would like to do is display floating-point numbers in a specific notation which resembles the scientific notation but with a mantissa set to zero. With the same floating-point number as above, it would produce:

```
0.100000e+001
```

In C, I believe it would be written this way:

```
printf("%.6E", foo);
```

Update: Well, actually I don't know how to do it in C as well.
Update2: The example using iostream formatting was incorrect. I modified it according to Michael Burr's comment.

Comment: Thanks but I really want to know how to do this without using printf

Comment: You're both wrong. *Neither* %.6E nor %.0f will make printf show a number in the desired format.

Comment: Also, `::std::ios::scientific` doesn't do what you say - it's an enumeration that gets printed as an int. You need to pass it to `cout::setf()` or use `std::scientific` which is a function that `cout::operator<<()` will use to set the IO manipulator. I hate iostream formatting (actually I pretty much hate iostreams).

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do this with ostreams, I think you'll need to use "facets".  This little-known part of C++ lets you control formatting pretty much however you like.

Here's a description of `num_put`, which is what formats the numbers in the way you don't like: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/locale/num_put/

You'll need to "imbue" your ostream (literally `ostr.imbue()`) with a locale containing the facet you'll create to format numbers the way you want.

I suggest starting by writing a function to convert a number to a string using the formatting you want.  Once you have that, if you wish to go whole hog and do the locale & facet stuff, you can (or maybe you'll decide it's too complex, which is what most people end up doing).